# jquery mobile error loading page with symfony URL

Tags: symfony1, jquery-mobile

I have a problem when loading a symfony URL like this

```
<li><a id="offers" type="button">Offers</a></li>
$("#offers").click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("/site/offers","flip",false,true);
})
```

instead if i load an "usual" URL like this

```
$.mobile.changePage("/index.php","flip",false,true);
```

it works fine.

PS:
using tag

```
<a href="/site/offers" data-transition="flip" rel="external">
```

it works fine except the transition.

Thanks

Comment: Whats your routing.yml look like? Can you access this url in the browser on a non-mobile client?

Comment: yeah i can access this url on a non-mobile version!
in my routing.yml i have nothing about /site/offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably let Symfony determine which web controller to use so you could use the url_for method:

```
<li><a id="offers" type="button">Offers</a></li>
$("#offers").click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("<?php echo url_for('/site/offers'); ?>","flip",false,true);
})
```

Alternatively you can hardcode it:

```
<li><a id="offers" type="button">Offers</a></li>
$("#offers").click(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("/index.php/site/offers","flip",false,true);
})
```

And jQuery Mobile ignores page transitions on external or no-ajax requests so if you want the transition to work within your link use:

```
<a href="/site/offers" data-transition="flip">
```